# Is the connected assumption necessary in the following theorem?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, algebras, quiver

I'm reading about the following facts from the book *'Elements of the Representation Theory of
Associative Algebras'* by Assem, Simpson, and Skrowronski. Note that the algebras involved are not assumed to be commutative. I would like to find a proof of the following fact, usually attributed to Gabriel.

**Theorem.**(?) Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra, where $K$ is an algebraically closed field. Then, there is an equivalence of categories $A$-mod $\to$ $KQ/I$-mod where $Q$ is a quiver and $I$ is an admissible ideal in the path algebra $KQ$.

My first question is whether or not the above theorem is indeed true.

The way to aforementioned book handles this fact is to first reduce to the case that $A$ is basic using theorem I.6.8. This theorem asserts the existence of a basic algebra $A^b$ and an equivalence of categories $A$-mod $\to$ $A^b$-mod.  In the next chapter, the book proves the following theorem.

**Theorem.** Let $A$ satisfy the assumptions of the previous theorem, in addition to it being basic and connected. Then there is a quiver $Q$ and an admissible ideal $I \subset KQ$ so that $A \cong KQ/I$.

Is the above theorem true without the connected assumption? If $A$ is connected, do we know $A^b$ is connected? Perhaps a connectedness assumption is missing in my first theorem?

Thank you!

[This question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950516/morita-theory-and-non-basic-path-algebra) lead me to believe the connectedness assumption is unnecessary but I have not found a reference for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case where $A$ is not necessarily connected is deduced from the connected case.  Indeed, let $A$ be any finite-dimensional $K$-algebra.  Then $A = A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_r$, with each $A_i$ a connected algebra.  In that case, $A-\operatorname{mod}$ is equivalent to $A_1-\operatorname{mod} \times \cdots \times A_r-\operatorname{mod}$.  Replacing each $A_i$ with a Morita-equivalent basic algebra $A_i^b$, we get that $A$ is Morita-equivalent to $A_1^b \times \cdots \times A_r^b$.  By the theorem you cite, for each $A^b_i$, there is a quiver $Q_i$ and and admissible ideal $I_i$ such that $A^b_i$ is isomorphic to $KQ_i/I_i$.  Taking $Q$ to be the disjoint union of the $Q_i$ and $I$ to be the ideal generated by all the $I_i$ in $KQ$, we get that $A^b_1\times \cdots \times A^b_r$ isomorphic to $KQ/I$.  Thus $A$ is Morita-equivalent to $KQ/I$.  This finishes the proof.

Note that if a quiver $Q$ is not connected and $I$ is an admissible ideal of $KQ$, then $KQ/I$ is not a connected algebra.  Indeed, if $Q$ is the disjoint union of the non-empty quivers $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, then $KQ/I \cong KQ_1/(I\cap KQ_1) \times KQ_2/(I\cap KQ_2)$.